# Issue a POST request with url_for in Flask

Tags: python, http-post, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to issue a POST request within a [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) template in [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). However, parameters are passed in via GET by default, and this particular method only accepts POST requests.

I tried specifying `_method`, as below, but it still passes the parameter with GET instead of POST.

```
<li><a href = "{{ url_for('save_info', _method='POST', filepath=s.name ) }}"><div class="nodes">{{ s.title}} - {{ song.owner }}</div></a></li>
```

(The error message is the same whether or not I `specify _method`).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `_method` arg.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All links are `GET` requests. You can't force a `POST`.

An alternative would be this:

```
@app.route('/save_info/<filepath>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def save_info(filepath):
  if request.method == 'POST' or filepath:
    ...
```

You'll have to find a nice way to force your code to ignore that you sent a `GET` request.

Comment: Hm, is there some other way of doing this without passing the information through the URL, then, the way forms do? This isn't actually a form per-se in the way it's presented to the user, but it's  the same idea (a selection presented to the user).

Comment: You can't send a `POST` request without AJAX or a form, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

You could either make a form that contains only a submit button, or send the POST using AJAX or some other client side scripting. As far as I know, you can't make a link send a POST, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a Middelway which search for a GET argument which overwrite the http method.
Look there: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/38/

Your new link will look like this:

```
<li><a href = "{{ url_for('save_info', __METHOD_OVERRIDE__='POST', filepath=s.name ) }}"><div class="nodes">{{ s.title}} - {{ song.owner }}</div></a></li>
```