# Why and how http method of current endpoint affects url_for behavior in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am using:

- [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) 0.12.2
- [Python](https://www.python.org/) 3.6.1

---

Consider this, isolated, example of the behavior I am pondering on:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hi/', methods=['POST'])
@app.route('/hi/<var>')
def hi(var):
    return ''

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GET or POST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="{{ url_for('path') }}">
            <input type='SUBMIT' value='GET'>
        </form>
        <form action="{{ url_for('path') }}" method='POST'>
            <input type='SUBMIT' value='POST'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>''')

@app.route('/path/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def path():
    return str(url_for('hi', var='Hello', var2='xyz'))
```

To make my intentions clear, I will briefly describe what is happening and what I am striving to understand:

1. `/hi/` endpoint has an ['optional' parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032066/can-flask-have-optional-url-parameters) (`<var>`), which is accepted only via GET request. 'Plain' (i.e. without arguments) `/hi/` endpoint can only be accessed via POST method.
2. `/path/` endpoint can be accessed via both GET and POST http methods. And it just returns path for `hi` generated via `url_for('hi', var='Hello', var2='xyz')`
3. Now, I would expect `/path/` to return the same string, regardless of which method was used to access it (GET or POST). But it is not the case: for GET it returns `/hi/Hello?var2=xyz` (as I, actually, would expect), but for POST I am getting `/hi/?var=Hello&var2=xyz` (which strikes me as odd behavior).

Through trials and errors I was able to find out that adding POST to methods allowed for `/hi/<var>` fixes the issue (`/hi/Hello?var2=xyz` is returned by `/path/` for both GET and POST), i.e.:

```
@app.route('/hi/', methods=['POST'])
@app.route('/hi/<var>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hi(var):
    ...
```

---

I hope, someone would be able to explain the following, for me:

1. Why is this (`/path/` returns different values for POST and GET) happening?
2. Is it possible to avoid this behavior, without allowing POST on `/hi/<var>`?

Answer (score 1):

I have stumbled upon answers thanks to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246889/issue-a-post-request-with-url-for-in-flask) =)

---

Addressing my own questions:

1. (*not 100% sure about that, would be grateful if someone confirmed that I am correct here*) `url_for` has an optional `_method` parameter, which is defaulted to the method that was used to return **current** view. So, `/path/` is really returning `return str(url_for('hi', var='Hello', var2='xyz', _method='GET')` when it was accessed via GET request and `return str(url_for('hi', var='Hello', var2='xyz', _method='POST')` if it was accessed via POST request. That is why allowing POST on both endpoints (`/hi/<var>` and `/hi/`) fixes the problem — if POST is allowed only for `/hi/`, then `return str(url_for('hi', var='Hello', var2='xyz', _method='POST')` is checking whether `var` is known only to `/hi/` (and it is, obviously, is not known to it). On the other hand, if POST is allowed on both endpoints, then `/hi/` and `/hi/<var>` are checked for the presence of `var` and `/hi/<var>` is correctly selected.
2. Given the previous point, the fix is pretty obvious now: `return str(url_for('hi', var='Hello', var2='xyz', _method='GET')` should be substituted for `return str(url_for('hi', var='Hello', var2='xyz')`, in the original snippet.