# Flask Session does not retain value between POST requests

Tags: python, session, flask

So I'm using flask to create endpoints as receivers and data processors. I have two threads of http POST requests, the first one is sent to the first route, similarly for the second one. The thing is I want the 2nd processor to be triggered only when the 1st one is, so I created a session key, to validate for the execution of the 2nd processor.

But no matter what I did, session key is always wiped when I sent POST to the second processor. Here's my code, which has been simplified. Pardon my amateur ablity to express the problem, I'm extremely new to coding.

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "abc"

@app.route('/first_processor', methods=['POST'])
def first_processor():
    data = {
        'message': 'json received',
        'json': request.json
    }
    cond = data['json']

    if cond['event'] == "message:received":
        session["key"] = cond['key']
        return redirect(url_for("second_processor"))
    else:
        return data

@app.route('/second_processor', methods=['POST'])
def second_processor():
    if "key" in session:
        print('OK')
    else:
        print("FAIL")
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I saw two minor problems. The first one is that

```
@app.route('/second_processor', methods=['POST']) `
```

only allows `POST` method, and

```
redirect(url_for("second_processor"))
```

is a `GET` request. And you cannot force a `POST` request. Even though, according to the documentation, there is a `_method`   parameter in the `url_for`  function.
Related question: [Issue a POST request with url_for in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246889/issue-a-post-request-with-url-for-in-flask)

The second problem is that you created the `data` variable inside the `first_processor` function, but you don't pass it to the `second_processor`.

```
 if 'key' in session:
        print('OK')
    else:
        print("FAIL")
-->    return data
```

you could either:

- pass the data inside the session,
- make data global ( not sure if it is a good practice though)
- store data in a file or db and read it inside second_processor.